# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в этом предложении? (3)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Подскажите, пожалуйста: правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в этом предложении?

**Образ Мцыри, который олицетворяется в произведении как стремление к свободе, — это также образ романтического героя, с глубокой трагической судьбой.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Последняя запятая не нужна, т.к. "образ ... с судьбой":

Образ Мцыри, который олицетворяется в произведении как стремление к свободе,- это также образ романтического героя с глубокой трагической судьбой.

Насчёт тире, спорно. Я бы оставил, задумка автора понятна: образ Мцыри - это ... образ героя

Comment: Большое спасибо!